# How to restrict user access to map services on ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, map-service

If we have all our map services published on one server, can we configure it such that our users can only see or access a only a subset of the map services?

Answer (score 6):

You will set up one of three types of security.

[image: Ags security]. 
After enabling security you need to first create the users and groups (either in the ags store,a management db, or a domain/ldap.
Then go to each service and enable for that group.
[image: Image2]
Note that you can only apply roles to services.
You need a separate role for each service.
Then put a different user in each role.
You have to go to each service to apply the role.

Comment: @NeoJigglypuff You are likely to attract more Answers if you Accept some/more of those already provided.  To do this use the big green tick next to them.